# Cache manifest - what happens to a cached page that links to an updated/invalidated manifest?

Tags: html, frontend, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

Imagine this scenario:

`/pageone.html` and `/pagetwo.html` both reference `/cache.manifest`. Neither page are explicitly mentioned in the manifest.

A user visits both `/pageone.html` and `/pagetwo.html` while **online**, so now both pages, and all the files in the manifest will be **cached** offline in their browser.

Now the `/cache.manifest` file gets updated, and so does `/pagetwo.html`.

The user requests `/pageone.html` again, and their browser will now refresh the `/cache.manifest` and all the mentioned files.

Now the user goes **offline**, and then visits `/pagetwo.html`. What happens?

- Will the new /pagetwo.html already be downloaded with the new manifest, even though it's not explicitly mentioned?
- Or will the browser just show the old /pagetwo.html with the new manifest?
- Or will the browser just show a page not available page?

Comment: It seems to me like trying it yourself would be quicker than waiting 13 hours for someone else to try it and tell you what happens.

Comment: @robertc Someone might just know, I'm happy to wait. I will try it myself when it becomes critical, and then I'll answer my own question, and then if anyone else wants to know the answer to the same question they can google it quickly and find my answer. I'm not forcing anyone to answer, I'm happy to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it. It will show the old version of the page (at least in chrome).

Comment: I had four files in a folder: manifest.appcache, page1.html, page2.html, and uselessimage.jpg. page1 and page2 have a manifest attribute pointing to manifest.appcache. manifest.appcache points to uselessimage.jpg. I visited page1.html in my browser, then page2.html. I then added a comment to manifest.appcache so the browser would redownload it and changed the text in the body tag of page2.html. After that I shut down the local server and tried to visit page2.html, and it showed how iot originally was before I changed it.

Comment: Okay so let's say both pages display uselessimage.jpg. After you shut down your server and revisit page2.html, does it show the new uselessimage.jpg or the old one?